# How can I model a drone medication delivery system in a database structure?

Tags: database

I have thought extensively about it and came up with these 2 classes:

```
public class Drone {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Serial Number is required")
  @Size(max = 100)
  private String serial_number;

  private ModelType model;

  @Max(500)
  private int weight_limit;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Battery capacity is required")
  private BigDecimal battery_capacity;

  private StateType state;

 }
```

and

```
public class Medication {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$")
  private String name;
  private float weight;
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")
  private String code;
  @Column(nullable = true, length = 64)
  private String image;
}
```

But I just can't figure out how to link them since each drone will be carrying medications. I still think I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `Drone` class has nothing to store a list of medications on board. For example `private Medication medications[];` in the Drone class.